# How to speed up cholesky decompositions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, statistics

I have to do several cholesky decompositions (function: chol http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/chol.html) of very large matrices in a for-next statement in Matlab. Is there any way possible to improve the speed of the decomposition? Can I perform the decomposition in multitasking (if so, how?) ? Thanks.

Comment: You can create a parfor loop to calculate these matrices in parallel. There are quite some restrictions to such for loops though. See info here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parfor.html You can also just open a second (third, fourth) instance of Matlab. That has been my favourite strategy for parallel computing.

Comment: Are your matrices `full` or `sparse`? If `full`, you could use Parallel Computing Toolbox and `distributed` or `gpuArray` (as well as using `parfor` to run several in parallel - across several machines if you have MATLAB Distributed Computing Server available).

Comment: Have you looked into an alternative factorisation such as QR? Is there anything that these matrices have in common, such that some work can be taken out of the loop? If not then parfor is the answer